# JavaScript event listener performance for hundreds of DOM elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I have a `<ul>` that has many children (close to 3000 items) and some of the `<li>`s have many levels. I've attached an event listener on 'click' (I'm using jQuery) which I use to toggle the visibility of the children of an `<li>`.

I'm wondering how having so many event listeners impacts performance. (There are at the very least 1000!). Is this a big issue for performance?

I'm not really seeing much of an issue performance wise with newer web browsers, but IE8 seems to be very slow. Is it madly irresponsible to just whack an event listener on everything?!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is a big whooping **YES**. **Yes, it will affect performance**. Event delegation was built for this exact thing. Instead of binding your handler to every single `li`, bind it to its parent, the `ul`. This way the `ul` will delegate the `click` event to `li`.

```
$("ul").on("click", "li", function () {
 //your code
});
```

Comment: Would be more helpful if you could support this with numbers. Saying it "affects performance" is not helpful at all. Of course it affects performance. The question is how much